# Can I reenchant an already enchanted item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got some nice Dragonplate armour now and I was thinking about enchanting it with something nice. My enchantment skill is not maxed out though, so I will only be able to put some mediocre enchantments on the armour.

Can I put some weaker enchantment on it now and later, when I have better enchantment skill, replace the enchantment with something new? Or can I only enchant plain, non-magical items? Is there a way to unenchant an item?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot replace enchantments, nor can you add to already enchanted items with the [*Extra Effect* perk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting#Skill_Perks).

It is better to wait until you have a high Enchanting skill and the Extra Effect perk before enchanting good equipment, unless you have the materials to make another one.

Comment: To be clear:  The Extra Effect perk does not allow you to add an enchantment to any items.  It allows you to select up to two when creating enchanted items.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Updated to make it more clear, otherwise it was very misleading information.